# JNI: Call a method from C++ that takes an Object

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a simple problem that I can't seem to find an answer.  I've written a method in C++ which should call a method in Java that takes an object.  For example, my Java code has:

```
public class MyClass {

    public class ReturnType {
    ...
    }

    public void methodToBeCalledFromC( ReturnType obj ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

And my C++ has:

```
const jclass classID = s_env->FindClass( className );
const jmethodID methodID = s_env->GetMethodID( classID, "methodToBeCalledFromC", "(LMyClass;)V" );

// The call.handler() function returns a reference to the ReturnType object
// This produces a compilier warning and causes a seg-fault.
s_env->CallVoidMethod( call.handler(), jmid, userInfo );
```

I've check the classID and methodID as well as the `call.handler()` is returning a jbject which I have called `NewGlobalRef()` for, so I think all that is ok.

Can a jobject be passed like this?

Comment: Do you have a jobject reference to the object you are want to call the method on?

Comment: Yes.  It is the return type of the call.handler() function call.  That class basically holds the object, and creates a Global ref to it to ensure it has the same lifetime as the c++ object that holds it.  If that doesn't work (which it didn't), I got an error much sooner than that.

Comment: What's the compiler warning you mention?

Comment: @Ernest Hey! That was it!  As I was copying the compiler warning, I noticed that the 'userInfo' wasn't a jobject!  Sorry!  I feel really stupid!  Post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the compiler warning -- it may be telling you something important!

Comment: The warning was: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'class UserInfo' through '...'; call will abort at runtime.